# Tensorflow, possible to downweigh gradients for certain data items

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gradient

Say I have a multi output model with outputs y_0 and y_1.
For some data examples I am confident that y_0 is correct, but know that y_1 may be a complete guess. My idea was to use a custom training loop and multiply by a calculated weight, but this does not seem to be working. Is there a way to do this through the keras api that may be simpler than this?

```html
            @tf.function
            def train_on_batch(x,y):

                y_true = y[:, 0]
                weights = y[:,1]

                with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                    y_pred = model(x, training=True)
                    print("ytrainpred ", y_pred)
                    loss_value_pre = loss(y_true, y_pred)   
                    loss_value = loss_value_pre * weights

                # compute gradient 
                grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)

                # update weights
                optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))

                # update metrics
                loss_1_train.update_state(y_true[:, 0], loss_value[:,0])
                loss_2_train.update_state(y_true[:, 1], loss_value[:,1)

                return loss_value
```

Answer (score 0):

In the method [compile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile) of the keras object you have a parameter called loss weights to do that, you only need to implement the lost functions that take one or other output and passed as an array of losses to the loss parameter, but this becomes quite impractical if you have many ys

Comment: The issue I see with this is that while you can set the weights for certain output variables, you cannot do so for individual data items.